# Spring Integration HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler with url parameter expressions

Tags: spring-integration, spring-el

I have a `HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler` which should make HTTP GET requests to an endpoint URI and, for each request, it should pass two URL parameters with values obtained from the flowing message's headers. How can I get a `Message`'s header values and apply them to each request made via the `HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler`?

So far I have tried configuring my handler as follows:

```
    SpelExpressionParser expressionParser = new SpelExpressionParser();

    Map<String, Expression> uriVariableExpressions = new HashMap<String, Expression>(2);
    uriVariableExpressions.put("userId", expressionParser.parseExpression("headers.userId"));
    uriVariableExpressions.put("roleId", expressionParser.parseExpression("headers.roleId"));

    HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler handler = new HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler(uri);
    handler.setHttpMethod(HttpMethod.GET);
    handler.setUriVariableExpressions(uriVariableExpressions);
```

but, when a message flows through and the HTTP request is made, the `Message`'s userId and roleId header values are not set as parameters in the request's URL. When debugging, I can see that the Message's headers and values are definitely in the flowing Messages. Is the spel expression correct?

Thanks,
PM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `uri` has to have placeholders to substitute your variables, e.g.:

```
http://foo.com/service?userId={userId}&roleId={roleId}
```

From other side, show, please, your `uri` and the logs, when you send a message.

Comment: Hello Artem, I did not have the placeholders in the uri itself. Once I added the placeholders as part of the uri, I then got a new error: `EL1008E:(pos 8): Field or property 'userId' cannot be found on object of type...`. So I then changed the spel expression to the following form: `"headers['userId']"` and `"headers['roleId']"` instead of `"headers.userId"` and `"headers.roleId"`, and now the URI parameters are being included and requests are being sent okay. Thanks again!